# use python to convert hebrew from html to pdf

Tags: python, html, pdf, hebrew

I have an html file which I want to convert to pdf. It has English and Hebrew. When I try to convert it using various methods -- such as pdfkit and xhtml2pdf -- then I get no good showing of Hebrew characters, as you can see in this picture.

The bottom shows the html, whereas the top two images show the unsuccessful attempt to convert to pdf.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

pdfkit worked once I used this https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_meta_charset.asp

Comment: and did you find a way to make pdf kit create a table of contents?